# Problemas com o bash - echo com char ! (exclamação)

Tags: linux, bash

Estou tentando passar uma senha como parametro a senha usa numeros depois do char `!`

exemplo:

```
root@LinDom:~# senha="teste!123"
senha="testevim /etc/hosts"
root@LinDom:~#
root@LinDom:~# echo ${senha}
testevim /etc/hosts
root@LinDom:~#
```

Como faço para dar um escape no char `!` ?

Queria que meu resultado depois do `echo ${senha}` fosse `teste!123`

Comment: Veja se é isto http://superuser.com/a/301330/162728

Comment: isso mesmo @GuilhermeNascimento vlw

Comment: senha='teste!123' não funciona?

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza testei do jeito que você digitou escrevi ali no exemplo o resultado

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza, desculpe não tinha percebido que você fez referencia com as aspas simples, isso deu certo sim, obrigado!

Comment: @SneepSNinjA de boas, acontece

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem 3 tipos de aspas no `bash`:

- Aspas duplas ("") : Com elas você pode usar strings e valores de variáveis. Ex:

`nome="Douglas"
echo "Olá $nome"
Olá Douglas`

- Aspas simples ('') : Com estas, a variável vai ter o valor exato que estiver dentro das aspas. Ex:

`nome='Douglas'
echo "Olá $nome"
Olá $nome`

- Aspas invertidas (``): Quando se usa estas quer dizer que vamos armazenar a saída do comando em questão. Ex:

inicio=`pwd /home/douglas`

Na sua situação você deve usar Aspas simples pois quer armazenar o valor exatamente como está.

```
senha='teste!123'
```

Comment: rapaz né que com aspas simples funcionou também...obrigado

Answer (score 2):

O @Douglas já disse tudo, mas já agora só mais um comentário explicativo do tal estranho comportamento: em bash `!...` corresponde a notação referente à história.

`!123` é usado para
expandir para o comando numerado com 123 na história.

```
$ history | grep '^ *123'
...
  123  vim /etc/hosts
...
```

ou seja o tal estranho elemento que aparecia na senha.

Análogamente:

- `!c` vai expandir para o último comando começado pela letra `c`
- `!!`  o comando anterior
- `!:2` o segundo argumento do comando anterior...